# How to design mysql database for large file management app?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am starting a new project in which we have to handle many files. This project stores the 50+ categorized scanned documents (pdf format) and manages it.

There are many categories like certificates, tax, audit_report, guarantees, and many more in which all the documents can be added multiple times. I have designed like this.

**tbl_clients**
id,
name,
email,
address

**tbl_citizenship**
id,
client_id,
filename

**tbl_tax**
id,
client_id,
filename,

**tbl_audit_report**
id,
client_id,
filename

If I design like this I have to make 50+ tables. Is this good practice? or please suggest me the right way.
Thank You

Comment: No. Have a documents table with a column identifying what kind of document it is in each case. So, 1 table instead of 50

Answer (score 1):

No its not good practice. The right way is to create one table with a column which indicates the type of the saved document. Example:

```
tbl_documents
id | type | client_id | filename
```

also make sure to have an index on the 'type' column.

Comment: More importantly, have a composite `INDEX(client_id, type)`.